# starting a docker service daemon breaks the vpn network

Tags: linux, vpn, docker

We have a current VPN connection with one of our partners and somehow I think there are some restrictions with their firewall because after issuing 'service docker start', I am getting this from the command line.

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop  docker.service
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

And then I no longer can ssh in to that server from our main management console. The only I was able to jump back to that server is if I SSH first to other servers that belong to that same network and then jump in to that server where I lost the connection.

The docker daemon is starting well on the server but the connection from our main management Linux server going to this server is lost.

It could be because of the virbr0 that was created the daemon was started?

Is there any workaround I can do with Docker so that it won't mess with our VPN?